# Skyrim missing stone texture near Winterhold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, there is a weird stone that seems to be missing a texture on one side.

Pic:
[image: picture of rock]
Location:
[image: location of rock]
Is this normal? And how do i fix it?
I tried restarting Skyrim, it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

There are many such graphical glitches in Skyrim.  The [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19/) addresses many of these issues, but its very hard to find all of them.  In case you are using the HD Textures, there is also an [unofficial patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31255/) for that as well you should get.

In case this is simply a glitch for your machine, you should try to [verify the integrity of your game cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335).  I recommend doing this step first.

Comment: Make sure your game is updated with the latest official patches before installing the USKP.